# PYSPARK_PYTHON in spark-env.sh gives error

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark

I have installed Spark on CentOS. This comes with default 2.6 Python. I would like to use the latest version so I installed it in a separate location /usr/local/Python-3.3.5. To use the Python API from Spark, I modified the spark-env.sh configuration file. It is not clear if I am using the right syntax. It gives a permission denied error when I start spark with ./pyspark command. This is what I have currently:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/Python-3.3.5/
```

I also tried `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/Python-3.3.5/` (without the export). Still having the same problem.

Can someone suggest what could be an issue? I also checked the owners of both Spark & Python and they both are owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to your executable python

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=[YOUR_PYTHON_PATH]/bin/python
```